# Is there a standalone Google Chrome executable?

Tags: google-chrome

[Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) is not completely standalone because it have a folder to install to, is there a version where it's just ONE file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if anybody has done this; compiling Chrome into a single file would be a pretty daunting task with little benefit (a folder is hardly less portable than a file).

However, you could simulate something like this. [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com) is a bootstraper *meant* to script installation of multiple components, but I have used it to consolidate tools and batch files into a single executable file. You would add the Chrome Portable folder as an embedded folder in the bootstrapper, then the only component you would add to the installation would be to run the Chrome executable. This could then compile into a single file. When you launched it, Chrome Portable would be unzipped into a temporary folder, ran, then cleaned up after it closed.

Comment: Well, if no one have done it before then Google Chrome Portable will have to do unfortunately.